# XML data type in SQL Server 2008 - Find values of all attributes starting with let's say "name"

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have xml data as :

```
<data>
    <x name="name0">val1</x>
    <x name="name1">val2</x>
    <x name="name2">val3</x>
    <x name="name3">val4</x>
</data>
```

How can a select query be formed to fetch values whose attribute name starts with "name" followed by 0,1,2,3 and soon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two approaches

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<data>
    <x name="name0">val1</x>
    <x name="name1">val2</x>
    <x name="name2">val3</x>
    <x name="other">val other</x>
    <x name="name3">val4</x>
</data>';
```

--This will read **all nodes** and use a classical `WHERE`

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT x.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS x_name
          ,x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS x_value
    FROM @xml.nodes('/data/x') AS A(x)
)
SELECT x_value
FROM CTE
WHERE x_name LIKE 'name%';
```

--This is pure `XQuery`

```
SELECT x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS x_value
FROM @xml.nodes('/data/x[substring(@name,1,4)="name"]') AS A(x)
```

### UPDATE

If you need the word "name" dynamically, you can use `sql:variable("@VarName")`

```
DECLARE @part NVARCHAR(100)='name';
SELECT x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS x_value
FROM @xml.nodes('/data/x[substring(@name,1,4)=sql:variable("@part")]') AS A(x)
```

Both queries will return the same (*val other* is filtered out):

```
val1
val2
val3
val4
```